# sql - check to see if an entry exists, if so update another field; else leave as is

Tags: sql-server

I have two fields in a table that contains data - Relationship and ReciRelationship. I need to create an MS Sql statement to check the following and update:

If ReciRelationship contains  Mother OR Father OR Sister OR Brother
Update that value into Relationship
else leave relationship as is.

I just have this and cant proceed further due to little experience with sql. Any help would be appreciated.

```
UPDATE EEParents_actual     
    SET Relationship = Relationship
                        where ReciRelation not in('Mother','Father','StepFather','StepMother','Brother','Sister' );
```

Comment: can you post the schema of the tables? how are the tables related with each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE EEParents_actual
SET ReciRelationship = Relationship
WHERE (ReciRelationship LIKE '%Mother%') OR  (ReciRelationship LIKE '%Father%') OR
      (ReciRelationship LIKE '%Brother%') OR (ReciRelationship LIKE '%Sister%')
```

Comment: Thanks Giorgos. Works great.

Comment: @Vijay Glad I was able to help you. You can mark my reply as answer if you like.